# Alternative to \+ in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, primes, predicate, built-in

I have a program that returns true if an integer is prime, and else false.

However I used the built-in predicate '\ +' which it turns out I am not allowed to use, how could I get around not using it?

```
is_prime(2).
is_prime(3).
is_prime(P) :- P > 3, P mod 2 =\= 0, \+ has_factor(P,3).  

has_factor(N,L) :- N mod L =:= 0.
has_factor(N,L) :- L * L < N, L2 is L + 2, has_factor(N,L2).
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you allowed to use `not(_)`?

Comment: No unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not/1 in Prolog is implemented with the combination cut-fail (so called NAF - [negation by failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure)).

Code should be (untested)

```
...
is_prime(P) :- P > 3, P mod 2 =\= 0, has_factor(P,3), !, fail.
is_prime(P) :- P > 3, P mod 2 =\= 0.
```